# Jquery live() click is making multiple instances of uploadify, how can I stop it from doing it

Tags: uploadify, jquery

Uploadify with live click and toggle is creating multiple instances of the upload button how can I stop it from doing that.

My code:

```
// Display sub comments Form
            $(document).find("div[id^='subreply-']").live('click', function(){
                    var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
                    $('#subboxes-' + num).toggle();


                    $('#file_upload1-' + num).uploadify({
                        'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
                        'script'    : 'js/uploadify.php',
                        'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
                        'folder'    : 'upload',
                        'auto'      : true,
                        'multi'     : false,
                        'onComplete' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

                                            $("#commentfile-" + num).val(fileObj.name);
                                       }
                      });





            });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me as if it's happening because the code you posted clearly intends for it to happen.  What exactly do you really want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this quick fix?

```
var uploadify_instances = {};

$(document).find("div[id^='subreply-']").live('click', function(){
            var num = this.id.split('-')[1];

            if(!uploadify_instances['#file_upload1-' + num]) {
              uploadify_instances['#file_upload1-' + num] = true;
              $('#subboxes-' + num).toggle();

              $('#file_upload1-' + num).uploadify({
                'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
                'script'    : 'js/uploadify.php',
                'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
                'folder'    : 'upload',
                'auto'      : true,
                'multi'     : false,
                'onComplete' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

                                    $("#commentfile-" + num).val(fileObj.name);
                               }
                });

            }
    });
```

Edit: yup, I've made it unnecessary complicated at first.

Comment: Your "if" statement needs some attention ... that leading "!" is all you need, and the explicit comparison to `true` should go away.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay great solution with the tip from @Pointy